# Cookies.set doesn't set the value in cookie (js-cookie)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, js-cookie

I'm trying to set the some data inside of cookie using js-cookie.
but somehow it's not setting in the cookie. following is my code:

```
const setCookie = (name: string, value: string, expires: Date) => {
  Cookies.set(name, value, {expires})
}
```

and this is the result when I console.log this line :

```
 UserId=1; path=/; expires=Thu, 09 Apr 2020 15:26:37 GMT
```

I thought that path=/ is the problem, so I've tried to set the path as well, but didn't work.
Does anyone have idea why is not setting into the cookie?

Updated:
data passed to name, value, expires are :

UserId, 1, Thu Apr 09 2020 11:26:37 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: can you show me an example of the data you are trying to put

Comment: @Quantumass Updated. I passed UserId, 1, and Thu Apr 09 2020 11:26:37 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: do it without expires to see if it's working

Comment: @Quantumass OH works! so I can't pass the custom expiration date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expires parameter should be a number which indicate how much days until your cookie will expire

just update your function as follow

```
const setCookie = (name: string, value: string, expires: number) => {
  Cookies.set(name, value, {expires})
}
```